# Jquery is not working in firefox os simulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-os

I am just trying to add some Jquery in my app. But my jquery code is not working in the firefox os simulator. It working fine in my desktop browser. Please have a look at the image I have attached. What is the wrong?

[image]

And this is the code I am using

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons you can't use inline javascript in FirefoxOS apps. You need to place your JS in its own JS file and include it.

Please see the beginners app for reference code: https://github.com/mdn/battery-quickstart-starter-template/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://jsfiddle.net/ to test your code.

Here is working code. Enjoy.

```
<button class='button1'>Toggle</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button1").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```